# instrumenting Spring HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway with AspectJ aspect

Tags: spring, maven, jboss7.x, spring-integration, aspectj

We are running our spring application on JBoss 7.1.1-Final
we need to intercept the execution of the sendAndReceive method in org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway, we have our AspectJ aspect that works fine with our own beans, but we are not able to weave (load time) the HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway class with it.
Is there any limitation in weaving springframework beans? Any suggestion on how to do it?
In our aop.xml we have

```
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug">
    <include within="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.*"/>
</weaver>
```

We also tried to add the weaveDependecies block in our pom as follows

```
<weaveDependencies>
  <weaveDependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
  </weaveDependency>
</weaveDependencies>
```

but it didn't help

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know that `sendAndReceive()` is a **protected** method. So, it is just invisible for weaver. As well as as any `final` methods, too.

Comment: Hi @Artem, thank you for your comment, you may have a point here, but I'm afraid the problem is at an higher level (so far). Just to test we tried to weave org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(..) that is a public non-final method, but yet no weaving.

Comment: I think we are missing something, in the logs we see many "weaving" debug messages, including our classes as well for example hornetq's but none related to spring classes (and as well for any EJBs or Servlet we have), it seems that EJBs, Servlet and spring related classes are not picked up by AspectJ weaver

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not a Spring user, rather an AspectJ expert.

The `sendAndReceive` method is protected, true. But in AspectJ this is not a problem, given the right pointcut, only in Spring AOP. So this is not the root cause if you use AspectJ LTW.

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/3.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/http/inbound/package-summary.html), in this package there are three classes with `sendAndReceive`, but each single one inherits it from class `org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport`. So maybe you want to `include within` that package or class, otherwise an `execution()` joinpoint in that class will be excluded from weaving.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this but it didn't make any difference. Is it possible that the Spring classes are simply not visible to the weaver due to the fact that AspectJ is initialized after all the Spring classes have already been loaded by the JBoss classloader? If this is indeed the case, is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for not answering for so long, but I was pretty busys since August. I just checked my SO inbox. If you still have not solved your problem, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), optimally a Maven build on GitHub, and probably I can help you. The information you provide is insufficient for finding the root cause of your problem.